# Combine elements from two lists

Tags: python, arrays, list

I want to merge two arrays in python in a special way. 
The entries with an odd index of my output array `out` shall be the coresponding entries of my first input array `in0`. The entries with an even index in `out` shall be the coresponding entries of my second input array 
`in1`.

`in0`, `in1` and `out` are all the same length.

Example:

The input arrays

```
in0 = [0, 1, 2, 3]
in1 = [4, 5, 6, 7]
```

shall be merge to the output array

```
out = [0, 5, 2, 7]
```

Is there a nicer way than to loop over the whole length of the inputs and fill my `out` 'by hand'?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension and select values from `in0` on even indices and `in1` on odd indices:

```
[in0[i] if i % 2 == 0 else in1[i] for i in range(len(in0))]
# [0, 5, 2, 7]
```

Comment: I don't get the whole syntax but I'll look it up. Thank you!

Comment: `i % 2 == 0`  is checking if th remainder of doing `i/2` is `0` . If it is `0` the index is even and an element from `in0` will be added, otherwise from `id1`. YW :-)

Comment: The same idea could be written more concisely as `[x[i%2] for i, x in enumerate(zip(in0, in1))]`.

Comment: the outer brackets and the `for i in range()` confused me since I am not that familiar with python. But I looked it up and list comprehension is a nice python feature I did't know about

Comment: Yes nice one @chepner

Comment: That also simplifies my own answer.

Answer (score 8):

If you're happy to make full list copy, this is simple with slicing:

```
>>> in0 = [0, 1, 2, 3]
>>> in1 = [4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> out = in0[:]
>>> out[1::2] = in1[1::2]
>>> out
[0, 5, 2, 7]
```

Comment: Very nice. Unfortunatly I simplified my example too much: My inputs are strings and `out[ 1::2] = in1[1::2]` apperently does not work with strings. But this is the nice and clean syntax I hoped for!

Comment: Very elegant solution. Should be accepted as answer!

Answer (score 5):

If you don't mind some verbosity...

```
from itertools import cycle

in0 = [0, 1, 2, 3]
in1 = [4, 5, 6, 7]

out = [pair[i] for pair, i in zip(zip(in0, in1), cycle([0,1]))]
```

How it works:

1. `zip(in0, in1)` is a sequence of tuples,  `(0,4), (1,5), (2,6), (3,7)`.
2. `cycle([0,1])` is an endless stream of alternating 0s and 1s to be used as indices in the tuples from step 1.
3. `zip(zip(...), cycle(...))` produces a pair of tuples and indices:

   ```
   (0, (0,4)), (1, (1,5)), (0, (2,6)), (1, (3,7)).
   ```
4. The list comprehension takes the correct element from each tuple.

In the end, the list comprehension is a general version of

```
[(0,4)[0], (1,5)[1], (2,6)[0], (3,7)[1]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Without using loops, but not in the exact same order you requested:

```
>> in0 = [0, 1, 2, 3]
>> in1 = [4, 5, 6, 7]
>> out = in0[0::2] + in1[1::2]
>> out
[0, 2, 5, 7]
```

**EDIT:** correcting the output order with itertools:

```
>> import itertools
>> in0 = [0, 1, 2, 3]
>> in1 = [4, 5, 6, 7]
>> out = list(itertools.chain(*zip(in0[0::2], in1[1::2])))
>> out
[0, 5, 2, 7]
```

Comment: This looks nice but I want to keep the order